# How to shrink imageview(change bound) and move downward

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-transitions

I want to move imageview downward to the center while shrinking its bounds, its like you are clicking on image and image moves out downward center and disappears.

With this code I'm changing imageview bounds but its shrinking upward

```
ChangeImageTransform imageTransform = new ChangeImageTransform();

            imageTransform.setDuration(1000);

            TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();

            set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL);

            set.addTransition(imageTransform); 
            set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
            set.addTransition(fade);

            TransitionManager.go(new Scene(relative),set);
```

Comment: Please add code here otherwise no one can understand your problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try these animations : https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/10/android-xml-animations-examples.html

Comment: Edited question